# How can i add custom function to twig (symfony3)?

Tags: php, twig, symfony

i added this code to service.yml

```
//app/config/services.yml
services:
TwigEkler:
  class: MainBundle\Twig\TwigEkler
  tags:
     - { name: TwigEkler }
```

and created this file

```
//src/MainBundle/Twig/TwigEkler.php
<?

namespace MainBundle\Twig;

class TwigEkler extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('gecis', array($this, 'gecisFunction')),
        );
    }

    public function gecisFunction($param)
    {
        if ($param == '4') {
            return 'FAT';
        }  else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'TwigEkler';
    }

}?>
```

and used it in twig

```
{{ gecis(level) }}
```

but i am getting this error

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unknown
>   "gecis" function in "gecis/gecis.html.twig" at line 24." at
>   C:\wamp64\www\deneme\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php line
>   573 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Syntax(code: 0): Unknown
>   \"gecis\" function in \"gecis/gecis.html.twig\" at line 24. at
>   C:\wamp64\www\deneme\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\ExpressionParser.php:573)"}

where is my mistake?

Comment: I think Your error is in service in Your tags declaration. Try replace tag name to `{ name: twig.extension }`

Comment: from the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: sorry for delay but doctrine drive me crazy :)
@ciurciurek ; changed there and nothing changed. but try to clear cache giv me new error
"[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]             
  Attempted to load class "TwigEkler" from namespace "MainBundle\Twig".  
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?    "
[at]DarkBee ; i read and follow the instructions but no success :(

Comment: i solved via this page http://amanvarshney.blogspot.com.tr/2011/12/how-to-make-twig-filter-in-symfony2.html

Comment: @MC_delta_T so what was wrong? You should post it as an answer so your question won't appear unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

create a directory  in your AppBundle "Extensions"

and create a file "TwigExtensions.php"

In that file you need to define:

```
namespace AppBundle\Extensions;
    
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use AppBundle\Helper\CommonHelper;
    
class TwigExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine) {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
    
}
```

Use

```
public function getFunctions() {
    //Define your function that you    
}
```

Then create the function that you have define in "getFunctions".

Now you can use that function on twig.